# How to drop muliple option from a select box and place it to another div using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<seelct id="country" multiple="multiple">
  <option id="">USA</option>
  <option id="">UK</option>
  <option id="">CA</option>
  <option id="">USA</option>
</select>

<div class="item-group"></div>
```

I need to drag the countries into this 'div'. Any help?

Comment: How do you mean you want to 'drag' the countries into this div?

Comment: What have you tried already? SO isn't a place for questions like "Will someone code this for me?"

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want to do is append the values of the countries into the `item-group` div. This would do it:

```
var group = $('.item-group'); //let's query this once
 $('option').each(function() {
   group.append('<p>' + $(this).val() + '</p>');
 });
```